# Adapter не распознает setter

Tags: java, android

У менять есть класс Н, созданный для адаптера. В классе М(адаптер) я вызываю сеттер из класса Н, но его не распознает, подчеркивает краснsv. Геттер работает.

Класс Н:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс М (Адаптер):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приводите код текстом, а не картинками!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас **mainItem** определён как **TextView**, а не **Zadacha**.